# Hosting TeamCity 8.1 & YouTrack in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, teamcity

I am a newbie to IIS (and administrative tasks in general). I am trying to host TeamCity and YouTrack in IIS to allow other web applications to be run on the same port. Solving the issue for TeamCity should also solve it for YouTrack, so this post is only about getting TeamCity to work.

I have followed the guide on [A Step by Step Guide to Hosting TeamCity in IIS 7](http://endjinblog.azurewebsites.net/2010/11/a-step-by-step-guide-to-hosting-teamcity-in-iis-7/) but I cannot get it to work. Whenever I enter *teamcity.mydomain.com* into the browser I end up at the default website (default IIS website that comes when installing IIS).

TeamCity is set to run on port 8080. Entering localhost:8080 in the browser opens up the TeamCity start page. Entering teamcity.mydomain.com opens up the default IIS website (as mentioned above).

The port number I changed in server.xml (TeamCity) is the one on the following line:`<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"`
The server farm for TeamCity is using IP 127.0.0.1 (is this correct, or should it be the internal IP on the LAN?). URL rewrite rule has been setup according to the link above: Using wildcards with "*" pattern and a local grouping with {HTTP_POST}, Matches the Pattern, where pattern is "teamcity.mydomain.com". The default IIS website is unchanged.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you. If you've come up with a solution, I'd be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Set BaseUrl as teamcity.mydomain.com